# Is it possible to cancel flags?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged an answer as I thought it would have been better as a comment. Then the user modified it and now it looks more like an answer.

My flag will be deemed invalid, lowering my flag weight... Can I cancel my flag now that I don't see reasons for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cancel a flag, but it doesn't matter much. In principle, moderators are supposed to take action based on the post's current current state, but choose the reason for flag dismissal based on the state the post was in when the flag was raised. In practice, it's a bit of a pain for moderators because there's no [indication that the post has been edited since it was flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/indicate-that-a-post-has-been-edited-since-being-flagged), but the worst that can happen is a slightly confused moderator, and even if your flag is declined, [it's not as if flag weight mattered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106614/remove-flag-weight-and-flag-validity-already).

For a not-an-answer flag where the poster has substantially improved their post in the meantime, it's usually fairly obvious what's going on.